# Always one selected on list <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, meteor

I have an input and users list. This input is a search box, so every time I type on the input it changes the users list reactively. How do I achieve that there's always one selected on the users list preferably the first list item then if I hover to other the selected changes and leaves to where I last hovered on. This is my html code:

```
<div class="user-container">
    <input class="form-control user-search" placeholder="Search by name" type=“text">
    <div id="userList">
        <ul>
                <li>
                    Bob
                </li>
                <li>
                    Charlie
                </li>
                <li>
                    Foxtrot
                </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

This needs javascript, cause I wanted to know which is selected. So I can get its data. Also can use up and down keys in changing selection. Doesn't have to be a code that works. Maybe just help me with the logic and give me some pseudocode.

Comment: _"it changes the users list reactively."_ How is list changed ? _"hover to other the selected changes and leaves to where I last hovered on"_ What is expected effect of hover at a list item ?

Comment: Using Meteor.js, particularly this EasySearch package. Hovering at a list item will make it as selected and only one must be selected and just highlight (grey background) if selected.

Comment: Also not just hover using mouse, can use up and down keys for changing selected list item, reference is facebook search bar.

Comment: Can edit Question to detail requirement includes using _"Using Meteor.js, particularly this EasySearch package."_ , and _"Also not just hover using mouse, can use up and down keys for changing selected list item,"_ ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `css` `:hover` , `:not()`

```css
ul li:hover {
  background: grey;
}
ul:hover li:first-child:not(:hover) {
  background: transparent;
}
ul li:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="user-container">
  <input class="form-control user-search" placeholder="Search by name" type="text"/>
  <div id="userList ">
    <ul>
      <li>
        Bob
      </li>
      <li>
        Charlie
      </li>
      <li>
        Foxtrot
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This needs javascript, cause I wanted to know which is selected. So I can get its data. Also can use up and down keys in changing selection.

Comment: @Unspeakable _"This needs javascript, cause I wanted to know which is selected. So I can get its data. Also can use up and down keys in changing selection."_  Description at comment not appear at original Question ? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

another approach `js` wise would be...

create a css class

```
.selected{
   /* css for selected class */
}
```

On page load, add this to `first-child`

```
$("some-first-child").addClass("selected")
```

on selecting any other class, `remove` it from above `li` and add it to new `li` class.

To setup a default, you can search for this class in html `body`

In case `$('body').hasClass` doesnt return `true`, you can always add it back toh the first `li` child.

Comment: Okay okay.. seems this is it, but then how would I change using up and down keys?

Comment: @Unspeakable :  you let the page load with default selection, on up /down of keys, remove css class from dom and add it to current class which is selected.The *catch* is, when up / down is done and user hasn't selected any, then you have to sweep the entire DOM and check for presence of *css-class*, if not present, then add to default `li` .... makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Jquery search

```js
$("input").on('input', function() {

  var val = $(this).val().toUpperCase();

  $("#userList li").each(function() {

    if ($(this).text().trim().toUpperCase().indexOf(val) > -1) {
      $(this).show();
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="user-container">
  <input class="form-control user-search" placeholder="Search by name" type="text">
  <div id="userList">
    <ul>
      <li>
        Bob
      </li>
      <li>
        Charlie
      </li>
      <li>
        Foxtrot
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want like this.

```
<style>
    .active{
        background: gray;
    }
</style>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
            $("ul li").mouseover(function(){
               $("ul li").removeClass("active");
               $(this).addClass('active');
            });
    });
</script>

<div class="user-container">
    <input class="form-control user-search" placeholder="Search by name" type=“text">
    <div id="userList">
        <ul style="width:100px;">
            <li class="active">
                Bob
            </li>
            <li>
                Charlie
            </li>
            <li>
                Foxtrot
            </li>
            <li>
                Bob
            </li>
            <li>
                Charlie
            </li>
            <li>
                Foxtrot
            </li>
            <li>
                Bob
            </li>
            <li>
                Charlie
            </li>
            <li>
                Foxtrot
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

with up and down key working.. I am working on this wait.